# Sendmail relay without authentication

Tags: linux, authentication, sendmail

I have an issue:when the email is sent from an address other than 127.0.0.1  the authorization is required even if ip is on the same machine.

How can I avoid to make request authorization for a given ip ?

Comment: Postfix would do this with `mynetworks`. Sendmail has an equivalent setting, I guess.

Comment: You should at least post relevant lines from the log file

Answer (score 1):

Sendmail by default allows to relay from local IP addresses.

Have you used `DontProbeInterfaces` (`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES`) to change it too?
[Such change is quite common on virtual web servers with email served elsewhere ]

Do you use local IP addresses assigned *after* sendmail daemon startup?

Comment: In my sendmail.mc I have define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES', `True')dnl